# Getting node/edge creation/removal statistics

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-python-driver

I am running a `Python (3.8)` script which uses `pip` library `neo4j 4.0.0` to interact with a community edition `neo4j 4.1.1` server.

I am running many queries which use `MERGE` to update or create if nodes and relationships don't exist.
So far this is working well, as the database is getting the data as intended.

From my script's side, I would like however to know how many nodes and edges were created in each query.
The issue is that in these `Cypher` queries that I send to the database from my script, I call `MERGE` more than one time and also use `APOC` procedures (though the `APOC` ones are just for updating labels, they don't create entities).

Here is an example of a query:

```
comment_field_names: List[str] = list(threads[0].keys())
cypher_single_properties: List[str] = []
for c in comment_field_names:
    cypher_single_properties.append("trd.{0} = {1}.{0}".format(c, "trd_var"))
cypher_property_string: str = ", ".join(cypher_single_properties)


with driver.session() as session:
    crt_stmt = ("UNWIND $threads AS trd_var "

                "MERGE (trd:Thread {thread_id:trd_var.thread_id}) "
                "ON CREATE SET PY_REPLACE "
                "ON MATCH SET PY_REPLACE "

                "WITH trd AS trd "
                "CALL apoc.create.addLabels(trd, [\"Comment\"]) YIELD node "

                "WITH trd as trd "
                "MERGE (trd)-[r:THREAD_IN]->(Domain {domain_id:trd.domain_id}) "
                "ON CREATE SET r.created_utc = trd.created_utc "
                "ON MATCH SET r.created_utc = trd.created_utc "

                "RETURN distinct 'done' ")
    crt_params = {"threads": threads}

    # Insert the individual properties we recorded earlier.
    crt_stmt = crt_stmt.replace("PY_REPLACE", cypher_property_string)
    
    run_res = session.run(crt_stmt, crt_params)
```

This works fine and the nodes get created with the properties passed from the `threads` `Dict` which is passed through the variable `crt_params` to `UNWIND`.

However, the `Result` instance in `run_res` does not have any `ResultSummary` inside it with a `SummaryCounters` instance for me to access statistics of created nodes and relations.
I suspect this is because of:

```
"RETURN distinct 'done' "
```

However, I am not sure if this is the reason.

Hoping someone may be able to help me set up my queries so that, no matter the number of `MERGE` operations I perform, I get the statistics for the whole query that was sent in `crt_stmt`.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the earlier neo4j version, you could write `n = result.summary().counters.nodes_created`, but from 4.0 the `summary()` method does not exist.

Now I found from https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/breaking_changes.html that `Result.summary()` has been replaced with `Result.consume()`, this behaviour is to consume all remaining records in the buffer and returns the `ResultSummary`.

You can get all counters by `counters = run_res.consume().counters`